# How to make a sliding image viewer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, viewer

Can anyone explain how to create a sliding image viewer using javascript or jquery? From the ones I've seen, it looks like all the images are side-by-side and then buttons move the images across depending on the width of that image. Which shows the next image. There's one of these image viewers [here](http://store.steampowered.com). I'm not after the scrollbar though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a nice plugin, then check out [AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/).

If you need a tutorial, check out [this excellent one](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/automatic-image-slider-w-css-jquery/) by Soh Tanaka :)

Or [here](http://www.kerrinhardy.com/2011/02/10/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-the-automatic-image-slider-w-css-jquery-from-soh-tanaka-in-zen-cart/), because Soh Tanaka's site is no longer available

Comment: Thanks! Worked great once I customised it. I used the tutorial one. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a jquery plugin here

http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/

that looks kind of like what you want - depends if you need the control or just want the cycling images.